# python plain text regex parsing

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a small parser that will extract data from a form.

The data will be posted in a consistent pattern all the time. As follows:

```
Panakamanana
104412=Trident of Corrupted Waters
104411=Immerseus' Crystalline Eye
104435=Stonetoe's Tormented Treads
104455=Reality Ripper Ring
99716=Chest of the Cursed Protector
104509=Laser Burn Bracers
104531=Haromm's Talisman
99722=Gauntlets of the Cursed Protector
104562=Ring of Restless Energy
104606=Gleaming Eye of the Devilsaur
99725=Helm of the Cursed Protector
99719=Shoulders of the Cursed Protector
104616=Ticking Ebon Detonator
105686=Hellscream's Pig Sticker
```

The only data I'm interested in is each integer before the = sign. I want to then be able to iterate over these so perhaps putting them in a dict or array or something would be great.

Comment: Split on `=` perhaps would be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get it done:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   next(f) # Skips the first line, which doesn't have =
   numbers = [line.split('=')[0] for line in f if len(line.strip())]

print(numbers)
```

If you want to use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "104412=Trident of Corrupted Waters"
>>> re.findall(r'^(\d+)', s)[0]
'104412'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `split` the string up using `'='` as the delimiter. The most Pythonic way to implement this would be to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [int(line.split('=')[0]) for line in your_lines[1:]]
[104412, 104411, ..., 105686]
```

Where `your_lines` is a `list` of the lines demonstrated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that as follows:

```
new_list = [int(line[:line.find('=')]) for line in your_list]

print new_list
```

Comment: You don't need `new_list = []`

Comment: @Burhan, But don't I need to initialize a list in which to add the data

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, Just like that?

Comment: @sshashank124 No, that would return a `NameError`. He means a list comprehension. Take a look at our answers and you will see what he means.

Comment: You can do `new_list = [int(line[:line.find('=')]) for line in your_list]` and get rid of the `for` loop entirely.